# react-native Dimensions 'window' height and width are reversed on iOS after device rotation

Tags: ios, react-native

Using RN 0.59.10.

On iOS When querying the Dimensions via the react-native component Dimensions, height and width for "window" are reversed, while "screen" remains sane after device rotation.

I honestly don't know what to do to try to resolve this as it appears that this is incorrect information coming from react-native itself.  I've dug through so many components and other things trying to track it all down and i've just found nothing that can help.

Google has been absolutely no help whatsoever.

```
Dimensions.addEventListener('change', ({screen, window}) => {
  console.warn(window);
  console.warn(screen);
});
```

Setting up a listener like that above will spit out two console messages that blatantly disagree with each other

{"scale":3, "width": 896, "height":414, "fontScale":1}
{"scale":3, "width": 414, "height":896, "fontScale":1}

They should match (on iOS anyway)

We could get away with not caring about this, except that react-navigation uses Dimensions(window) to calculate landscape or not and as a result RNN adjusts menu items as if they are in a landscape orientation with extra space for the notch on iPhoneX-series devices.

Here's a couple of images to show you what i mean
[image: Landscape]
[image: Portrait]

Comment: Does that mean that the screen doesn't change?

Comment: When you rotate your phone the width and height becomes reversed as now the longest part of the screen is the bottom/top one (width), while the height is the shortest part of the screen (left/right)

Comment: @hongdevelop the screen does indeed rotate, but the reported dimensions are reported as if it hadn't, almost as if it's behind one step.  For example, an iPhoneX might report 896 width x 414 height in portrait mode, but when i rotate to landscape, now it is reporting 414 width x 896 height.

Comment: @Auticcat yes, but the width in landscape should be 896 but it shows as 414 and vice versa.  Android does not have this issue, and reports the appropriate width in landscape and portrait.